# How to create a graph in networkx from a sparse matrix?

Tags: python, networkx, data-science

I have a fairly large sparse matrix. The sparse matrix have elements in the below format. I want to create a graph network using a networkx library. Now, how should I approach?

> Row and column are nodes and they are connected if the value of the matrix element is 1.

```
In [44]: print(a)

(0, 0)    1
(1, 2)    1
(1, 3)    1
(2, 3)    1
```

Comment: Is your matrix stored as a scipy sparse matrix? If so, there's a command for that: [link](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_scipy_sparse_matrix.html)

Comment: Yes. it is scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at

[from_scipy_sparse_matrix](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_scipy_sparse_matrix.html)

The call looks like `G=nx.from_scipy_sparse_matrix(A, parallel_edges=False, create_using=None, edge_attribute='weight')`

`A` is the sparse matrix.

If `parallel_edges=False`, then the entry is considered an edge weight

`create_using` says what kind of graph it is.  It defaults to `nx.Graph`.

If `create_using` is `MultiGraph` of `MultiDiGraph`, and `parallel_edges=True`, and all edges are entries, then a `2` would mean 2 edges.

Otherwise the entries are treated as edge attributes.